# How to register action filter in .NET 6

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

I have this validation filter class.

```
public class ValidationFilter : IAsyncActionFilter
{
    public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        if (!context.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var errorsInModelState = context.ModelState
                .Where(x => x.Value?.Errors.Count > 0)
                .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value?.Errors.Select(x => x.ErrorMessage)).ToArray();

            var errorResponse = new ErrorResponse();

            foreach (var error in errorsInModelState)
            {
                foreach (var subError in error.Value)
                {
                    var errorModel = new Error
                    {
                        FieldName = error.Key,
                        Message = subError
                    };

                    errorResponse.Errors.Add(errorModel);
                }
            }

            context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(errorResponse);
            return;
        }
        await next();
    }
}
```

In ASP.NET 5, we add ValidationFilter like below

```
        services
            .AddMvc(options =>
            {
                options.EnableEndpointRouting = false;
                options.Filters.Add<ValidationFilter>();
            })
            .AddFluentValidation(mvcConfiguration => mvcConfiguration.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<Startup>())
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);
```

How to I add it at `Program.cs` in .NET 6?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In .Net6, We use `builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews()` instead of `services.AddMvc()`. So you can just set like this:

```
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add<ValidationFilter>();
});
```

More about `.NET 6` new configuration can refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

Comment: If you don't need views, AddControllers() would do the trick also.

Answer (score 2):

If you are only building API, you can use the following:-

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers(config =>
{
    config.Filters.Add<ValidationFilter>();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define a class which inherited from `ActionFilterAttribute`
that adds a header to the response as per the below sample code:

```
public class ResponseHeaderAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly string _name;
    private readonly string _value;

    public ResponseHeaderAttribute(string name, string value) =>
        (_name, _value) = (name, value);

    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)
    {
        context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add(_name, _value);

        base.OnResultExecuting(context);
    }
}
```

Then you can add the filter in your Program.cs file (based on dot net 6 new console template):

```
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add<ResponseHeaderAttribute>();
});
```

Now you can use it in your controllers for example:

```
[ResponseHeader("my-filter", "which has the value")]
public IActionResult DoSomething() =>
    Content("I'm trying to do something");
```